# regex for url parsing

Tags: php, url-parsing

how to parse this url `http://site.com/forum.php?id=1&page.php?id=1` to be like this

```
(
[0] => http://site.com/forum.php
[1] => 1
[2] => &page.php
[3] => 1
[4] => &next.php
[5] => 2
)
```

the regex I've been stuck like this `"/\?(.*?)=/i"` and the output like this:

```
(
[0] => http://site.com/forum.php
[1] => 1&page.php
[2] => 1&next.php
[3] => 2
)
```

Comment: You want [`parse_url()`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and then [`parse_str()`](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php). Also, that URL is malformed as there can only ever be one `?`.

Comment: thank for your help. i will learn this function